# Where is the "shut down" program located?

Tags: windows

In windows 7 when you click start...then the shut down button. what program is it calling to do the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command-line process "shutdown.exe" which is generally the go-to for programmatic shutdowns/restarts.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx

This does the actual shutting down. The various windows or dialogs you see asking you to choose how you want to shut down (shut down, sleep, hibernate, restart, log off) and/or asking you to confirm you want to do what you said you did are just part of the taskbar/start menu program, explorer.exe (which is also the Windows Explorer executable).

Answer (score 10):

You can always use where.exe to find things like this:

```
C:\>where shutdown.exe
C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe
```

Though this is definitely not a Stack Overflow question.